# How to represent a hex address in a string using little endian format?

Tags: c++, c, string, binary, hex

Ok, suppose I want to store the address `0xcdddd298` in a C string so that it stores the bits for this address in little endian format.  How would I do this?  Would it be something like `\x98d2ddcd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It would be `"\x98\xd2\xdd\xcd"`.

But I'm not sure why you'd want to store an address in a string.